# Model ANOVA or marginal ANOVA for detecting significance

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, anova, lme4-nlme, interpretation

I have recently faced a weird way of finding a significant variable.

Let the model be

$Cholesterol=Sex+FamilyHistory + Sex*FamilyHistory$

where the * denotes the interaction, sex and FamilyHistory are both two-level factors, and we assume that the study is nested inside cities. Further, assume that the fitted model is a linear mixed model with City in the random effect [random intercept].

Having the model above, we are interested to find out whether Sex has a significant effect on response.

What I normally do is to fit the model and look at the p-value of Sex coefficient in the marginal anova (simply using `summary(nlme fit)` in R). However, I have been told that I should make a null model like

$Cholesterol=FamilyHistory$

Or maybe! ($Cholesterol=FamilyHistory + Sex*FamilyHistory$)

and compare it with the full model using ANOVA (simply `anova(full.model, null.model)` in R).

So which one do you recommend?

**UPDATE: as @Stefan requested**, I give an example in R using the built-in example on `lme` manual. Sorry that the example is in a different context.

Let the full model be [it is the same as fm2 in the lme example in R]

```
full <-
  lme(
    distance ~ age + Sex,
    data = Orthodont,
    random = ~ 1,
    method = 'ML'
  )
```

Now the goal of the analysis is to find whether **Sex** is significant or not (obviously on the response)!

What I do is to look at the p-value from the sex coefficient from the full model.

```
 r1 = summary(full)
 r1$tTable
                 Value  Std.Error DF   t-value      p-value
(Intercept) 17.7067130 0.83154591 80 21.293729 1.057125e-34
age          0.6601852 0.06209293 80 10.632212 5.740140e-17
SexFemale   -2.3210227 0.74306676 25 -3.123572 4.478461e-03
```

that suggests a significant (in $\alpha =10^{-2}$) deviation for females than males. However, I have been told that the true way of finding the Sex effect is to form a null model by excluding Sex and comparing the resulting model with the full one:

```
null <-
  lme(
    distance ~ age , # Here Sex is removed
    data = Orthodont,
    random = ~ 1,
    method = 'ML'
  )
anova(full, null)
   Model df      AIC      BIC    logLik   Test  L.Ratio p-value
null     1  4 451.3895 462.1181 -221.6948                        
full     2  5 444.8565 458.2671 -217.4282 1 vs 2 8.533057  0.0035
```

As you see the pvalue here ($0.0035$) is slightly smaller than the p-value from the full model ($4.478461e-03$). I understand that the statistics are different, in fact, anova uses the $\chi^2$ distribution and test of coefficients applies $T$ distribution. ***However, I need to know which one is the proper one!***

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. The example makes it clear now. I'll delete my answer as it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Since the t-test compares the individual model terms to the reference level (Intercept), I wouldn't use it either to figure out whether `Sex` is significant or not. Those p-values will change depending on what you define as your reference level. Since you are dealing with factors, I agree with @SalMangiafico that you could simply use `car::Anova()` to get a table that shows the significance of the individual factors, including `Sex`. Comparing models using `anova()`, tests (as far as I understand) whether the explanatory power of one model is higher than the other...

Comment: ... by adding and removing `Sex` for example (full vs. null model) you can figure out whether one model accounts for more variation in the data than the other but not whether the effect `Sex` is significant in itself. For example you could add another covariate (or factor) to the model that increases the explanatory power of the model but it may not show up significant in itself when you look at it in a ANOVA-type table.

Comment: @Stefan thanks for the comments. I am not quite sure about the term **explanatory powe**. As far as I realize the full mode is different from the null by only Sex. Then the only source of difference in models is sex. as a result anova reflects the effect of sex. On the other hand, as you truly pointed out, coefficient p-vale reflect the relative effect of Sex for Females compare to the baseline (male+mean response and mean age). Now the question is: how we should define the effect of sex (is it relative to other terms or only single term as in car:::Anova). I am still looking for good answer:)

Comment: By explanatory power I mean how well the fitted model can explain the underlying data, that is which predictor combination leaves the least amount of unexplained variation in the model. Figuring out this specific set of predictor variables is what I meant by model selection. `anova()` can be used to do that, i.e. compare competing models **relative** to each other with respect to variation explained. ...

Comment: ...In the example above, I would say taking `Sex` out of the model will decrease the variation explained and hence `Sex` should be kept in the model (as can be seen by the lower AIC, ... , as well as the p-value). I think it depends if you want to know whether `Sex` in general is an important variable for your model, or whether you want to specifically know whether there is a significant difference in Cholesterol between males and females for which I would do `car::Anova()`. ...

Comment: ... Therefore, I think that the p-values are based on different null hypotheses and hence not comparable (although they might be close). See also `?anova` under the heading **Value**.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan. Explanatory power is now clear to me, thanks. I totally understand your view. "..In the example above, I would say taking Sex..." I think that Including Sex in the model is equivalent to testing for its levels (as in coefficient p-values). Other words, if the sex levels (male/females) are significant then overall Sex is significant, is not it? Then the anova and t-test should be the same or very close in values.

Comment: I think if you use the p-value from `anova(null, full)` will answer whether adding `Sex` will significantly increase the variance explained in the model. I am not sure if you can conclude from this test that the factors of sex are significantly different as well... For this I would use `Anova()` and a posthoc test if you have more than two levels. Maybe someone else here on CV will be able to answer whether using the p-value from `anova(null, full)`, or from (`car::Anova(full)`), or from `summary(full)`, can all be interpret the same way. I think this is the answer you are after, correct?

Comment: @Stefan thank you for your reply. Agree, they are all means of detecting effects. Yes I am looking for the best tool.

Comment: Yes, this appears to be the heart of the question:  for a lme object, is it better to use a likelihood ratio test (`anova.lme(full, null)`), an F test (`anova.lme(full)`), or a Wald chi-square test (`car::Anova(full)`)...

Comment: @SalMangiafico thanks, $anova.lme(full)$ is equivalent to $summary(full)$

Comment: Yes, but only if the effect you are considering has only two levels.  That is, if the data had three levels of *sex*, the *summary* function would give you a different kind of information.

Comment: @SalMangiafico So I am wondering why there are p-values for the coefficients when they are useless (according to your comment)?

Comment: I didn't say p-values for coefficients were useless. (...?)  It's just a fact that the output for *anova.lme* will be different than that for *summary* if the variable in question (*sex* in this case) has more than two levels, that is, if it is represented by more than one dummy variable.